# Error: Invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, file-upload, nestjs, multer

I have this nest controller (Running in AWS Lambda) that receives a zip file from a vue app:

```
const validationPipes = new ParseFilePipe({
  validators: [new FileTypeValidator({ type: "application/zip" })],
});

MulterModule.register({
  storage: multr.memoryStorage(),
});

@Controller()
export class LinkedInController {
  @Post("/linkedin-upload")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("linkedin-archive-file"))
  public async uploadLinkedInArchive(
    @UploadedFile(validationPipes)
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    const zip = new AdmZip(file.buffer);
    console.log(zip.getEntries());
  }
}
```

This throws this error:

```
Error: Invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at Object.loadFromBinary (/var/task/node_modules/adm-zip/headers/entryHeader.js:209:23)
```

This is the File object received by the nest controller:

```
{
  fieldname: 'linkedin-archive-file',
  originalname: 'Basic_LinkedInDataExport_06-09-2023.zip',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/zip',
  buffer: < Buffer 50 4 b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 4 e ef bf bd ef bf bd 56 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0 e 00 00 00 52 69 63 68 20 4 d 65 64 69 61 2 e 63 73 76 ef bf...1329408 more bytes > ,
  size: 1329458
}
```

However when I run the API locally everything works fine. But I can't think of what about Lambda environment or API Gateway would interrupt the delivery of the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A whole day of confusion but here is the fix. You need to specify your binary media types for your gw api otherwise it will get treated as utf-8 text which in this case manifested itself by losing the signature data.

`binaryMediaTypes: ["multipart/form-data", "application/zip"]`

```
public api = new LambdaRestApi(this, "RestApi", {
  handler: this.handler,
  deployOptions: { stageName: "butter-cv-api-stage" },
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: this.corsOptions,
  proxy: false,
  binaryMediaTypes: ["multipart/form-data", "application/zip"], // <-----
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html