# How to Download a ZIP file using AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to download files using AWS Lambda triggered by an API Gateway endpoint, for this, my lambda function code compiles several files from S3 and creates a zip file (within the lambda `/tmp/` directory) containing the specified files.

I'm having some trouble when downloading the file. I understand I have to return within the lambda response the file I want to download as a IO Stream, encoded in base 64. But when I test the API endpoint using postman and saving the response body as a `.zip` file and I try to open it it says:

> Unable to expand "response.zip". It is in an unsupported format.

.

I was taking [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) as an example, but what's different here is that the example downloads images instead of zip files.

my lambda handler method:

```
require 'logger'
require './lib/reports'
require 'base64'

$logger = Logger.new($stdout, level: Logger::Severity::INFO)

def handler(event:, context:)
    $logger.info("Starting execution of lambda. AWS_REQUEST_ID: #{context.aws_request_id}")

    prefix = 'reports'
    path = event['path']

    reports = Reports::ReportsZipper.new(prefix, path)
    
    reports.download_and_compress_files

    zip_file_path = reports.zip_file_path

    zip_file = File.new(zip_file_path).read()

    lambda_response = {
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/zip' },
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': Base64.encode64(zip_file).force_encoding('UTF-8'),
        'isBase64Encoded': true
    }

    return lambda_response

rescue Exception => e
    $logger.error("Error processing. Event: #{event}, Error: #{e.message}")
    { isBase64Encoded: false, statusCode: 400 }
end
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not a Javascript person, but should `reports.download_and_compress_files` be `reports.download_and_compress_files()` (with the brackets)? You could also test by uploading the zip file to s3 and check if it looks okay. This will help you determine whether the problem is with the zip file or the Return method.

Comment: Also to note, the documentation that you followed sets up a `proxy` lambda function, this might be a possible source of your issue. Proxy lambda's function differently than normal Lambdas and are more open in terms of how they process and respond to requests.

Comment: Is the encoded data being decoded anywhere?

Comment: I would assume, that it is decoded whenever you download it, i'm not sure about that

Comment: I had the exact same issue but with PDF. Here is how I fixed mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448037/error-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature

Comment: i just added 'application/zip' to the accepted binary types in my Gateway api but it still keeps throwing the same unsupported format when opening it

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using API Gateway to download a ZIP, look at putting the ZIP file into an Amazon S3 bucket, presign the ZIP file and get the presign URL.

Once that is ready - use a Service like Amazon SNS to send out a notification message with the presigned URL. Then users can download the ZIP from the Presigned URL in the notification message (see below).

This approach and implementation details are described in this AWS DEV article:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html)

**UPDATE**

Here is the app you build if you follow the instructions in the previous AWS link. For example, assume I want to get all images that are tagged **Bird**.

I select the tag in the app and click **Download**.

[image]

The app dynamically creates a ZIP of all images with this tag (there are 3 images with this tag as shown in the app). After a few mins - i get an email with the presigned URL.

[image]

When I click that - I get my ZIP with the images.

[image]

***Note - if i click the link after the presigned ULR expires, I can no longer get the S3 object***.

For more information about presign - read:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: your approach seems interesting, what do you mean by "presign"?

Comment: You can presign an object in a S3 bucket using an API call. WHen you do this, you can set a time limit - for example - 60 mins. After you presign an object - you get back an URL that someone can use to download an object within the specified time. For example - in the PAM app - we can download a ZIP of all images by clicking on the link in the notification message that SNS sends.

Comment: See my update to show a bit more detail

Comment: I tried your approach but it seems it doesn't fit this use case, as the SNS will send an email to every email subscribed to it. This lambda aims to download files just for the client that interacts with the api

Comment: Use SES to send email to a specific email address then as opposed to a subscription model.